# ActionBarSherlock: Collapsible item crash on orientation change ICS

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have a collapsible menu item that is defined in XML like this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/searchMenu"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="withText|always|collapseActionView"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/collapsible_edittext"/>
```

Here's the collapsible_edittext.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
android:inputType="text"
android:hint="@string/search"/>
```

When the item is expanded, and you change the orientation of the phone, it crashes giving this error in logcat:

07-24 08:59:19.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1284): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:     Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class android.widget.TextView$SavedState instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/searchMenu. Make sure other views do not use the same id.

If I remove the android:id="@+id/searchMenu", everything works fine but I need the item id in my code. This error only happens on ICS (It even works in the jelly bean emulator) and I'm using ActionBarSherlock 4.1.0

Comment: The error seems pretty clear. Do you have two views with the same ID?

Comment: I just found the answer, I guess android uses the same id for a collapsed item? God knows... thanks for taking the time to answer I love what you did with ABS and viewpager nice work mate :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the problem, in fact it was not even linked with ActionBarSherlock (I removed action bar sherlock from my project and it was still crashing).

I only needed to add an id to my EditText and that's it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/collapsibleEditText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="@string/search"/>
```